# Excel VBA Comparison with Two Attributes

Tags: excel, vba, compare, range, countif

I want to compare data between two worksheets using VBA. Normally, I would just use a COUNTIF() function or use a loop, but in this case I want to compare values from two different columns (combined, they would represent a distinct value) to the corresponding values in two different columns on another sheet.

[image]

In the example shown, I want to compare the 4 different permutations highlighted to the other sheet, to see if those 4 unique permutations exist in the other sheet. For example, if in the other sheet there is "AD7 - Abidjan" I want that to flag as a difference and have the cells highlighted or stored somewhere else. The other sheet may contain more or less (or zero) variations.

I'm not sure how to use a COUNTIF using data like this. I prefer not to concatenate data/move it into another range. Is there a way to run this analysis without manipulating the data?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `COUNTIFS()` ?

Comment: I haven't used COUNTIFS() before in this context. What I am trying to set up is a loop, so for each cell in the two ranges highlighted, it should compare to two different ranges in the other sheet. As in.. B2 + D2 is one value in the loop, and then it compares to all values in those two columns in the other sheet. Can you provide an example of how it might be used in this context?

Comment: I think @TimWilliams was nicely pointing you in the proper direction.  Please try what he suggests and we'll help when you run into issues.

Comment: This is commonly handled with `CONCATENATE(B2,"-", D2)` or by using `&` (`B2&"-"&D2`) in the formula.  You create a new index using the combined columns.  You do not have to create a new column to do this.  If you looking only for existence between two sheets, you can use `MATCH` with the new index.

Comment: Here is the example of how to use countifs: =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B:B,B2,Sheet2!D:D,D2) You could use conditional formatting for your highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following loop can be used to compare both fields in each sheet:

```
For Each i In Sheets("First_Sheet_Name").Range("First_Column")

Set rng = Sheets("Second_Sheet_Name").Range("First_Column")
Set rng2 = Sheets("Second_Sheet_Name").Range("Second_Column")

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, i, rng2, i.Offset(0, 2)) = 0 Then

  [Do something here]

End If

Next i
```